# How to make sure a collection only contains one of each of the implementations of an interface

Tags: java, collections, instanceof

I have an Interface `MyInterface` with numerous implementations and a Collection `Collection<MyInterface>`.

Now **how** can I **make sure** that there's **no** two **elements** in this Collection are **of the same type**?

And **how** can I **prevent** any **entry** from **being overridden**?

Meaning that there's at any given point in time only ever 1 instance of each implementation in the Collection.

For obvious reasons I can't add a default `equals(Object obj)` implementation to the interface.
Nor can I guarantee in any way that each of the implementations overrides the `equals(Object obj)` method (obvious but in here for the sake of thoroughness).

The only way I currently see is to create an abstract Class `MyAbstractClass`. But that seems overkill(?)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make sure"? Prevent it from ever happening, or check afterwards? Basically I think you'll want to call `getClass()` on each instance, and keep a `Set<Class>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `Map<Class<?>,MyInterface>` instead of a `Collection<MyInterface>`. The key would be the implementing `Class`. This would ensure that at most one instance of each type can be added to the `Map`.

Here's how you can initialize the map and add entries to it without overriding existing entries:

```
Map<Class<?>,MyInterface> map = new HashMap<>();
...
if (!map.containsKey(obj.getClass())) {
    map.put(obj.getClass(),obj);
}
```

Comment: How would I prevent an entry from being overriden?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T You can check if `map.containsKey(obj.getClass())` before you call `map.put(obj.getClass(),obj)`.

Comment: Added a second question. Would be much obliged if you could add your comment to your answer :) - Always trying to anticipate what brings other users to the question

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you'd like, see Collections.newSetFromMap for how to implement a Collection backed by a Map. Be aware that at runtime, your map could be filled with all kinds of classes as keys. You could use `Map<Class<? extends MyInterface>, MyInterface>` to get at least a compile-time protection.